# python 2.7 word generator

Tags: python, python-2.7

Algorithm: take input on how many letters to go back, for loop to loop a-z, lock the first character, loop the second character, lock the first two, loop the third, and so on and so forth. The out put will look like a, b, c, d... aa, ab, ac, ad... aaa, aab, aac... and so on. I am very new to python. I have something that cycles through the alphabet, but my problem is to lock the first and cycle the second and so on.

```
w = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
n = input ("# of characters: ")

for a in range(0,n):
        for i in w:
                print i
```

Comment: Can you use built-in modules? `itertools` in particular would simplify this dramatically.

Comment: I can use built in modules. I am very new so I do not know what they are, or each ones capability.

Comment: Then I'd take a look at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), specifically [the `combinations` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). For the record, an efficient way to convert the output of functions like `combinations` from a generator of `tuple`s to a generator of `str` is to wrap it, changing `for tupval in itertools.combinations(...):` to `for strval in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.combinations(...)):` so you never even see the `tuple`s; they're converted back to `str` as they're produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid huge RAM requirements, use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate a single output at a time, handling the "locking" for you:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Not needed on Py3, only on Py2
from itertools import combinations

w = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# Don't use input on Py2; it's an implicit eval, which is terrible
# raw_input gets str, and you can explicitly convert to int
n = int(raw_input("# of characters: "))

# You want 1-n inclusive on both ends, not 0-n exclusive at the end, so tweak range
for wdlen in xrange(1, n+1):
    # Generator based map with ''.join efficiently converts the tuples
    # from combinations to str as you iterate
    for wd in map(''.join, combinations(w, wdlen)):
        print wd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
l= ['']
for i in range(input):
    l = [letter + item for letter in alphabet for item in l]
    for item in l:
        print(item)
```

I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Note: This involves storing _huge_ `list`s of temporaries. Each loop creates `26 ** (i+1)` `str` of `len == i + 1`, so you'll need somewhere in the vicinity of 16 GB of RAM for length 6 words, 400 GB or so to handle length 7 words, and around 11 TB for length 8. I'd strongly recommend not doing this; the CPU work is bad enough, but the page thrashing will make this truly terrible.

Comment: What if I took it from a temporary to a txt file? Would that relive some pressure? So instead of print save it to file.